# htaccess redirect to https for an already Re-Written URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is my htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect to HTTPs for register
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} register
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# don't do anything for images/css/js etc
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|woff|map)$ - [NC,L]

# redirect to HTTP for all other pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !register
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [PT,L]
```

I've got a register page with an URL like *hxxp://www.example.com/index.php?register* and the htaccess is redirecting correctly to HTTPS.

Now I also want my buy page(*hxxpp://www.example.com/buy*) **to redirect to HTTPS**. This page's real URL is *hxxp://www.example.com/index.php?buy*

Please advice me on how to modify my htaccess rule to take care of this need.

Comment: Your URI scheme is a bit confusing. On one hand you have `/index.php?register` and on the other hand you have `/buy` (which is internally rewritten to `/index.php?products&type=buy`. Why not having `/register` (rewritten to `/index.php?register`) too ?

Comment: @JustinIurman: Sorry it was a typo in the URL. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex alternation in your `https` rule:

```
# redirect to HTTPs for register
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(register|buy)
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

**Make sure this is very first rule** in our htaccess.

Comment: Tested it before. Not working. The site is comprised of Clean URLs as well as long URL with multiple queries. Also http://example.com/buy is an already rewritten URL and I want it to be HTTPS. So I think {QUERY_STRING} won't work in that scenario. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: check updated rule and **make sure this is very first rule** in our htaccess.

Comment: Yes, it's working. But I want to to use the QUERY_STRING condition also. Can I use this : 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /buy [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} register
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

Comment: Yes definitely you can use that but make sure that rule is first rule.

Comment: Changed my htaccess to http://pastebin.com/YqME6PS2 Not working. Not sure whether my OR condition is correct.

Comment: On Line #15 you have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/buy [OR]` Remove `[OR]` there to make it work and test in a new browser.

Comment: Thanks its working. Why remove [OR] ? Can you please explain ?

Comment: Because you have `!` for negative conditions. In boolean algebra reverse of `a or b` is `!a and !b`